# immutable.js & react.js setState clears prototype of the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I have the following code in component:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = Immutable.fromJS({
            user : {
                wasChanged : false,
                firstName : false,
                lastName : false,
                address : {
                    street : false,
                }
            }
        });
}
onEdit({target: {dataset: {target}}}, value) {
      this.setState(function (prevState) {
          return prevState.setIn(['user', target], value);
        });
  }
render() {
    var user = this.state.get('user').toJS();
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when I try to update the value in *onEdit* I see that *prevState* has different prototype set. I don't understand why or what am I doing wrong. I see this in console

```
> Object.getPrototypeOf(this.state)
src_Map__Map {@@__IMMUTABLE_MAP__@@: true}

> Object.getPrototypeOf(prevState)
Object {}
```

After the state has been changed it goes to render where it of course can't find *get* function or anything from Immutable

Using react with addons 0.13.3.

Comment: Is it because it should be a simple object with keys and not fancy Immutable?

Comment: Any specific reason that you want to use `immutable`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it as a key on state.

```
this.state = {
  data: Immutable...
};
```

Currently the reason you can't use an Immutable object as state is the same reason you can't do `this.state = 7`: it's not a plain JavaScript object.

Roughly the operation looks like this:

```
React.Component.prototype.setState = (changes) => {
  batchUpdate(() => {
    // copies own properties from state to the new object
    // and then own properties from changes to the new object
    var nextState = Object.assign({}, state, changes);

    this.componentWillUpdate(...);
    this.state = nextState;
    queueDomUpdateStuff(this.render(), () => this.componentDidUpdate());
  });
};
```

Comment: Got it, Thanks. I was on the right track. Also thought that this is the reason. Do you know where I can read some best practices about using immutablejs with react?

Comment: It means that it will merge only the values/keys of the state object and not the values of its children? I mean it will not do the deep merge, basically replacing the value of the `user` property in my example

Answer (score 2):

Components' `state` should be a plain JavaScript object; *values* of that object can be Immutable values. Supporting Immutable values as state is discussed in [issue 3303](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3303).

Comment: Ok, so this might be supported soon. Thanks. Do you know where I can read some best practices about using immutablejs with react?